# Evidence for Avatar swapping Glitch

Tags: jumanji, jumanji-the-next-level

At two different points in Jumanji - The Next Level, the characters come across glowing green water that allows them to switch Avatars.

Several entries on the [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/JumanjiTheNextLevel) page state that this is hinted at being a glitch due to the broken machine rather than an intended feature.

> Game-Breaking Bug: In-Universe; it's heavily implied that the water that allows the characters to switch bodies is a result of the game being broken and not an actual feature, and it quickly comes in handy during the climax.

> New Rules as the Plot Demands: Jumanji now has an entirely new landscape to explore, new villains, new player characters (along with the ability to accomodate more than five players), and a function to let players change their avatar during a game in progress. Justified due to its magic and the fact it's broken and implied to be glitching; that last new feature is even hinted to be such a glitch and probably not intended by the game.

> Wrong Genre Savvy: Shelly and Ruby immediately suspect that the green, electrically-charged water surrounding the Jumanji Fruit contains some horrible peril. Turns out, it's just a bug of the game that allows them to swap avatars.

Having watch the film I completely missed these hints, and it looked to me like the functionality was intended the glowing water being a colour-coded hint. Can anyone fill me in on the hints that suggest Avatar swapping is a bug not a feature of The Next Level?

Comment: The fact that they could use it the way they did made me think it was a new game mechanic. Also the movie is called "the next level" and new levels often adds new mechanics.